# ASP.NET MVC - Deny access to a folder to users who are not logged

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-config

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I've a subfolder that has within it, javascript and html files. Particularly index.html (within the subfolder) launches a new website that uses these javascript files.
So, when it performs redirect from an ASP.NET controller to index.html (when the user perform some action), all works properly, and the page index.html is shown.
My goal is to deny access to index.html and all files in the folder "subfolder" when current user is no logged in.
Whereas I have configured the whole sessions management, and everything works properly, and I added the following lines to ASP.NET project Web.Config:

```
<location path="subfolder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

when I try to access the link https://localhost:.../subfolder/index.html without being logged in, however I am able to access the page.

Any idea??

Comment: yes! Unfortunately I'm sure

Comment: Does the authorization work for the index.html if you remove the path attribute? You could also try setting allowOverride="false" for location element.

Comment: ok, allowOverride="false works for me! But now I need to hide real path from addressbar, that is I'd like user can just reach pages throught links. For example: instead www.mysite.com/subfolder/page.html => www.mysite.com/page. I need a function that allow me to do this when('/page') showme(/subfolder/page.html